# javascript / threejs - detect when a key is released

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, listener, three.js

I'm using this javascript keyboard library for threejs, and it seems as though it is able to detect when a key is released. How would I incorporate this into my project? Here is the documentation:

http://learningthreejs.com/data/THREEx/docs/THREEx.KeyboardState.html

and here is how I currently detect which key is pressed:

```
if (keyboard.pressed("left")){ 
//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the source for threejs, there's a line

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", this._onKeyUp, false);
```

You're adding a handler, listening for the keyup event.

The MDC docs for addEventListener:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers my question. Are you suggesting I put that code into my project to listen for the keyup event, and then a corresponding function called _onKeyup? If so, that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: document.addEventListener("keyup", function(){alert('keyup')}, false);
works for me.  What you're doing is registering the function (the second argument) to be called on the "keyup" event.  The MDC docs are pretty good for figuring out all of the parameters and a few examples.